# How do you set the date format in a Azure Data Factory Data Flow JSON Sink?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data flow which has an XML file as a source and a JSON file as a sink. When the JSON file is generated date fields are being written as "dd/MM/yyyy" and I would much rather have ISO 8601 format. e.g. "2012-03-19T07:22Z"

Secondly how can you specify the format on an import? My import is in the format "dd/MM/yyyy" which I have no control over and suspect there's a risk it only works correctly right now because all the days are over the 12th.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had 2 dates in my data source, 1 had a projection of string and the other date. The one which was string was outputting to my json exactly as it came in, the other just didn't read the date from the source.

Fixing these to both be date and then setting the default format on the source corrected the read and they both now default to yyyy-MM-dd when exporting as JSON.

Didn't find a way to change the output if I needed something else though

[image: Data format]